# find on page/element widget javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

Is there a widget or function in javascript that duplicates functionality of browser "Find on Page?" I want user to type in to search input, which then finds each occurrence of value and highlights. Also includes found # of # with next and previous buttons. It would be great if there were a widget. If not maybe function to find multiple occurrences of string?

[Find on Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p4Hs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Window.find to search for any element on page.
Basically you are searching in the DOM and Window is the parent object.

```
<form action=""  id="form2">
<div>
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="submit_form" onclick="checkInput()" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>

function checkInput() {  
var query =document.getElementById('search').value;  
window.find(query);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, neither answer was quite what I wanted. I actually went a different way by using table filter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
Required strings have been underlined.

```
<!doctype html>
```

contains demo

John Resig

George Martin

Malcom John Sinclair

J. Ohn



$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );